# Dragging div does not work in IE 7 & 8

Tags: javascript

I am using the following function to drag a div by a handle:

```
function enableDragging(ele) {
    var dragging = dragging || false,
        x, y, Ox, Oy,
        current;
        enableDragging.z = enableDragging.z || 1;
    var grabber = document.getElementById("myHandelDiv");
    grabber.onmousedown = function(ev) {
        current = ev.target.parentNode;
        dragging = true;
        x = ev.clientX;
        y = ev.clientY;
        Ox = current.offsetLeft;
        Oy = current.offsetTop;
        current.style.zIndex = ++enableDragging.z;
        console.log(dragging);

        window.onmousemove = function(ev) {
            pauseEvent(ev);         
            if (dragging == true) {
                var Sx = ev.clientX - x + Ox,
                    Sy = ev.clientY - y + Oy;
                current.style.top = Sy + "px";
                current.style.left = Sx + "px";
                document.body.focus();
                // prevent text selection in IE
                document.onselectstart = function () { return false; };
                // prevent IE from trying to drag an image
                ev.ondragstart = function() { return false; };                  
                return false;   
            }
        };
        window.onmouseup = function(ev) {
            dragging && (dragging = false);
        }
    };
}    

function pauseEvent(e){
    if(e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    e.cancelBubble=true;
    e.returnValue=false;
    return false;
}
```

> I have two problems:
>
> 1. Does not work in IE 7 & 8, for some reason i get no errors whatsoever.
> 2. Text is selected on some browsers while dragging causing the drag to appear laggy

I initiate the drag like this:

```
var ele = document.getElementById("divDragWrapper");
enableDragging(ele);
```

> Update, am now getting this error in IE:
>
> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'target': object is
>   null or undefined
>
> On this line: current = ev.target.parentNode;

Comment: Do you have a good reason to not use something like jqueryui __draggable__ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `ev = ev || window.event` to all eventhander functions. Older IEs don't pass the event object within arguments. Also `target` is rather `srcElement` in those browsers.

For example:

```
grabber.onmousedown = function(ev) {
    ev = ev || window.event;
    var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
    current = target.parentNode;
        ...
}
```

Another thing is, that older IEs can't attach `onmousemove` to the `window`. You can use `document` or `document.body` instead.

See the code in action at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zxuk/1/).

Comment: Error went away but still not moving

Comment: Works in all browsers except for IE 7 & 8.. it just wont move there

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zxuk/), it's made up of your code. Only I can imagine why it wouldn't work in older IEs, is that you're using `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;` for your `#myHandelDiv`.

Comment: I've only IE10, but the code works fine when emulating 7 or 8.